# Transfer of value from register controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a problem with transfer value from method "OnPostAsync" to Register.cshtml. ViewBag doesn't work.
How to resolve this problem.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var db = new ApplicationDbContext(_optionsBuilder.Options);
        var email = db.Users.Where(s => s.Email == Input.Email);
        if (email.Count() != 0)
        {
            ViewBag.pom = 100; // this doesn't work
            ViewData["duplicateEmail"] = "Email is already taken";
            return Page();
        }

...
```

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <h4>@ViewData["duplicateEmail"] error: @ViewBag.pom</h4>
            <hr />
...
```

Comment: `ViewData["duplicateEmail"]`- is it work?

Comment: yes ViewData works

Comment: Then `ViewBag.pom` will also work. Please show your View code where you are uisng `ViewBag.pom`

Comment: in the above code "Viewbag" is underlined in red, as if some "using" was missing

Comment: Add your View code to the question.

Comment: I can't -> "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." I'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: Okay! Paste it to the comment.

Comment: I see there is nothing wrong! Can you remote access with team viewer please?

Comment: This problem is in marked file:  https://ibb.co/rZFk6Jt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2#weakly-typed-data-viewdata-viewdata-attribute-and-viewbag):

> `ViewBag` isn't available in Razor Pages.

For more information around *why* isn't available out-of-the-box, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6754#issuecomment-326763351), which includes a few comments from Damien Edwards himself:

> We purposefully didn't add ViewBag because I wanted to discourage its use.
>
> ...
>
> ViewBag uses dynamic which in our testing introduces a measurable performance impact on the processing of pages or views that use it. As such, I'd rather it not be available by default.

The solution is to either use an explicit property (as you're doing for `ReturnUrl`)  or just use `ViewData` (as you're doing for `duplicateEmail`).

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the viewBag with a viewData :

```
ViewData["pom"] = 100; 
ViewData["duplicateEmail"] = "Email is already taken";
return Page();

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <h4>@ViewData["duplicateEmail"] error: @ViewData["pom"]</h4>
            <hr />
```

**ViewBag was intentionally left out in razor pages.**